# Framer Motion animating the background on mousemove not working properly with useSpring

Tags: reactjs, animation, tailwind-css, css-animations, framer-motion

I made a component called GradientBackground that basically what does is make a  that has an interactive background. It has a background CSS property set to a radial-gradient which position is dynamically set to the position of the mouse. Similar to what [cal.com](https://cal.com/es#:%7E:text=Todo%20lo%20que%20necesitas%20en%20una%20aplicaci%C3%B3n%20de%20programaci%C3%B3n) does in the linked section.

I was happy with the result but now I want the radial-gradient to move smoothly and slowly towards my mouse's position instead of it's position being set on my mouse's. I haven't seen that implementation anywhere so I decided to use framer-motion since I've been messing around with it for a while.

This is so far what I've been able to accomplish

```
const GradientBackground = ({
  backgroundColor = '#535350',
  gradientColor = '#f5cb5c',
  height = 200,
  width = 200,
  radius = 100,
  className,
  children,
  ...props
}: GradientBackgroundProps) => {
  const mainRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

  // Initialize position of gradient
  const x = useSpring(50)
  const y = useSpring(50)

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleMouseMove = (e: MouseEvent) => {
      if (mainRef.current) {
        // Get the dimensions of the container
        const containerRect = mainRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
        const containerWidth = containerRect.width
        const containerHeight = containerRect.height

        // Calculate the position in a percentage within the container
        const mousePositionInContainerX = Math.round(
          ((e.clientX - containerRect.left) / containerWidth) * 100
        )
        const mousePositionInContainerY = Math.round(
          ((e.clientY - containerRect.top) / containerHeight) * 100
        )

        // Set the position
        x.set(mousePositionInContainerX)
        y.set(mousePositionInContainerY)

        console.log(`x: ${x.get()}, y: ${y.get()}`)
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove)
    }
  }, [mainRef, x, y])

  return (
    <motion.div
      ref={mainRef}
      className={className}
      style={{
        background: `radial-gradient(${width}% ${height}% at ${x.get()}% ${y.get()}%, ${gradientColor} 0%, ${backgroundColor} ${radius}%)`,
      }}
      animate={{ transition: { duration: 0.5 } }}
      data-scroll-container
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </motion.div>
  )
}
```

As you can see and if you try this component for yourself here (you can see my old code too): https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-matsumoto-58rr4k?file=/src/App.tsx

Is that I'm logging in the console the position of x and y and yes it seems like its updating correctly. What I don't know for sure is why is the component not updating at all. I'm not sure if even using useSpring is the correct way of doing what I want to do, since I'm not very familiar with the other hooks and animations, components and values I suppose that there are better ways to do so.

tl;dr: Check the example. I want the gradient to move with my mouse similar to my old implementation, but instead with a spring transition using Framer Motion.

I tried using useMotionValue, useSpring and useMotionValueEvent to trigger the update of the x and y value and also the rerender of the component but I haven't been able to do so.

What I've noticed if that if I manually refresh the page, the gradient used to update to where my mouse was before I refreshed. I wasn't able to reproduce this interaction tho.

Answer (score 0):

## Motion Values

`useSpring(50)` will return a motion value. These are somewhat separated from React and the render loop. That's to unsure performance. React will *not* rerender a component using a motion value, even though the motion value is changing (their internal state).
You might have noticed that your gradient *is* moving whenever you alt+tab between active windows. React then re-render as a side effect, moving your gradient (only one time, one re-render per alt+tab).

## Subscribing to motion changes

You can let react know that you want to re-render when the motion value changes.
It's as simple as hooking into the `onChange` of the spring/motion value.

```
  const x = useSpring(50);
  const y = useSpring(50);
  const [currentX, setCurrentX] = useState(x.get())
  const [currentY, setCurrentY] = useState(y.get())
  useEffect(() => x.onChange(latest => setCurrentX(latest)), [])
  useEffect(() => y.onChange(latest => setCurrentY(latest)), [])
```

Each `setCurrentX` call will also trigger a re-render.
The [documentation](https://www.framer.com/motion/motionvalue/##responding-to-changes) goes into more detail.
Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-drake-nj4pgc) with updated code.

## Why did motion make this so difficult?

You might be wondering why motion values don't trigger re-renders out of the box. It would be quite an performance impact to trigger re-renders as the  default behavior.

I consider the hooks to be a bit clucky to use in this way.
A helper within the library to subscribe to changes would probably make it easier to avoid this pitfall.

Though, I should point out that, these hooks are **designed** to pass directly into the `style` prop of a `motion.div`. The inner workings of the `motion.div` will handle all the re-rendering and subscribing for you.

You might be able to simplify this all by wrapping your gradient background inside a `motion.div` and passing in the hook value immediately.
Something [like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-sanne-fp98pc?file=/src/components/GradientBackground.tsx)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! Not only fixed my problem but also taught me a lot about how Framer Motion works. I think your first solution works best for me.